# Is there any way to don't store an anonymous user on Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Data is stored on Cloud Firestore and protected by Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

It means that you need to be signed in to *application A* to manage the data.

Those data can be read (aka listed) from another *application B* in the basis of a DB query result and for that there is no needed to the users to be signed in.

To make the data to be listed from *application B* we need to allow anonymous sign in method on Firebase Authentication.

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) states that:

> These temporary anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed up to your app to work with data protected by security rules.

Since then there are lots of anonymous uses on Firebase Authentication and there is no plan to convert an anonymous account to a permanent one (as seen [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account)).

A code was created to manually delete those anonymous users time by time.

Based on that is there a way to don't store anonymous users on Firebase Authentication or to persist a single credential for that trusted application to access protected data?

Comment: I don't really understand the question or what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You can use Realtime-Databasee since you can set up own rules over there.

Comment: @DougStevenson Suppose you have an e-commerce and you want to protect all the data. It means that to manage that data the users needs to sign into an application. Now suppose that you have another application where you want to show part of those data without requiring the users to sign into this application. You can sign in anonymous from that application while protecting your data but you will have lots of anonymous records on Firebase Auth, so how can you can get rid of it? Again, there is no plan to convert an anonymous account to a permanent one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete any user account, both normal and anonymous, you will have to [use the Firebase Admin SDK to delete the account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).  It will be up to you to figure out which ones to delete.  You can either [list all the users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) and try to figure it out from there (which could be time consuming if you have a lot of users), or query a database where you store additional user account information.  I suggest maintaining your own database.

Firebase does not provide a way to automate this.  You will have to write code and run it periodically.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. As I wrote, code (using the Admin SDK ) is done already in order to figure out anonymous users and delete them. The problem is that we need to run it periodically. 

Having something like a trusted credential for an application where you don't require the users to be sign in to read the protected data and  at the same time you don't want to have those anonymous users as it happens now might be a solution to be considered in the future.